# ASP.NET MVC portal/CMS - controller and widget design?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, content-management-system, portal

I'm currently working on a portal using [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery) portlets/sortable/draggable that also includes a content management system, all in [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) 2. Only administrators are able to change the layout/content of the site currently.

Each view gets the personalization for a page (from the base controller) based on Controller and Action. Then the view loops through the widgets and calls renderaction for each of them.

Currently, I have View + "Edit" actions on each view to set the page into edit mode. As I'm duplicating code there must be a better way, but I can't see it for the life of me!

How would you implement an action that allows each View to be edited?

```
public ActionResult Legal()
{
    PageModel model = GetPageSetting();
    return View("Portal", model.PageSetting.Master.Path, model);
}

[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
public ActionResult LegalEdit(EditorModel e)
{
    PageModel model = GetPageSetting("Legal", "Home", true);
    return View("Portal", model.PageSetting.Master.Path, model);
}
```

//This is in the base controller

```
protected PageModel GetPageSetting(string action, string controller, bool isEditing)
{
    PersonalizationProcess personalizationProcess = new PersonalizationProcess();

    string path = string.Format("~/{0}/{1}", controller, action);
    string userName;
    bool isAuthenticated;

    if (User == null)
    {
        userName = "TestUser";
        isAuthenticated = false;
    }
    else
    {
        userName = User.Identity.Name;
        isAuthenticated = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
    }

    PageSetting setting = personalizationProcess.GetPageSetting(userName, isAuthenticated, path);
    PageModel model = new PageModel();
    model.Act = action;
    model.Con = controller;
    model.IsEditing = isEditing;
    model.PageSetting = setting;
    return model;
```

Answer (score 0):

Without looking at the code, is hard to give you specific advice on how to avoid code duplication. But in general you want to "Extract Method/Extract Class" 'till you can't extract any more :)... Also, you can use some of the MVC infrascructure to help you do some of the repetitive code ie. ModelBinders and ActionFilters.

Maybe you can post some of the view/edit actions' code to point you in a better direction

Comment: I've added the code for one view of the portal page. The site has to be SEO as well, so I can't just render the widgets and make ajax callbacks either.